# How can I echo visual swatch on a phtml Magento 2

Tags: attributes, magento2, layered-navigation

I would like to please your help. 
I want to echo an attribute that I created Brand which is a Visual swatch (i use Ajax Layered Navigation, so I have an option with text and Swatch image). 
I manage to echo each product the brand text that belongs but I can't echo the image. 
Can you please help me?

```html
 
 <?php $attributeValue = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'); ?>
       <?php if(strlen($attributeValue) > 0): ?>
       <?php echo $attributeValue; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/233339/84221